Calculate new column value based on max for group in Pandas Dataframe
I have dataframe containing list of subjects + dates of dispensing, one subject has more Dates of Dispensing and one single Date of dispensing for one subject can occur several times. Here is example:
{'Subject': {1449: 'CZ100030006',
  1786: 'CZ100030006',
  1958: 'CZ100030006',
  1964: 'CZ100030006',
  4067: 'CZ100030006',
  4119: 'CZ100030006',
  4143: 'CZ100030006',
  4441: 'CZ100030006',
  4467: 'CZ100030006',
  4530: 'CZ100030006',
  4532: 'CZ100030006',
  4585: 'CZ100030006',
  4703: 'CZ100030006',
  4767: 'CZ100030006',
  4850: 'CZ100030006',
  4888: 'CZ100030006',
  4974: 'CZ100030006',
  4987: 'CZ100030006',
  5108: 'CZ100030006',
  5476: 'CZ100030006',
  9768: 'CZ100030005',
  9815: 'CZ100030005',
  9822: 'CZ100030005',
  9837: 'CZ100030005',
  9852: 'CZ100030005',
  9853: 'CZ100030005',
  9889: 'CZ100030005',
  9945: 'CZ100030005',
  10009: 'CZ100030005',
  10050: 'CZ100030005',
  10052: 'CZ100030005',
  10060: 'CZ100030005',
  11532: 'CZ100030005',
  11582: 'CZ100030005',
  11640: 'CZ100030005',
  11722: 'CZ100030005',
  13267: 'CZ100030005',
  13339: 'CZ100030005',
  13354: 'CZ100030005',
  13655: 'CZ100030005'},
 'Date Dispensed': {1449: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  1786: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  1958: datetime.date(2024, 6, 21),
  1964: datetime.date(2024, 6, 21),
  4067: datetime.date(2024, 9, 16),
  4119: datetime.date(2024, 9, 16),
  4143: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4441: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4467: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4530: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4532: datetime.date(2024, 9, 16),
  4585: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4703: datetime.date(2024, 10, 11),
  4767: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4850: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4888: datetime.date(2024, 7, 19),
  4974: datetime.date(2024, 10, 11),
  4987: datetime.date(2024, 9, 16),
  5108: datetime.date(2024, 10, 11),
  5476: datetime.date(2024, 10, 11),
  9768: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  9815: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  9822: datetime.date(2024, 8, 28),
  9837: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  9852: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  9853: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  9889: datetime.date(2024, 8, 28),
  9945: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  10009: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  10050: datetime.date(2024, 7, 4),
  10052: datetime.date(2024, 8, 28),
  10060: datetime.date(2024, 8, 28),
  11532: datetime.date(2024, 6, 20),
  11582: datetime.date(2024, 6, 5),
  11640: datetime.date(2024, 6, 20),
  11722: datetime.date(2024, 6, 5),
  13267: datetime.date(2024, 9, 25),
  13339: datetime.date(2024, 9, 25),
  13354: datetime.date(2024, 9, 25),
  13655: datetime.date(2024, 9, 25)}}


What I want is to add to df new column where TRUE is if date of dispensing is 2nd to max FOR THAT GIVEN SUBJECT and False for all other cases.

So for Subject CZ100030005, there will be True in added column if in that row Dispensing date is 28AUG2024, because this is 2nd max value of date dispensed.
I am able to find max value per group maxima = df_cov.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed'].max(), but I am not able to find 2nd to max.
And I am not able to do 2nd step at all, i.e. to make new column True/False based on whether 2nd to max value equals/not equals to current row Date Dispensed value.
Can you advice please?

Performance is important?

@Dmitry543 has the correct logic, but this should used groupby.transform and a comparison with itself in the function:
# ensure datetime
df['Date Dispensed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Dispensed'])

# find largest second(s) for each group
df['new'] = (df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed']
               .transform(lambda x: x==x.drop_duplicates().nlargest(2).iloc[-1])
            )

Output:
           Subject Date Dispensed    new
1449   CZ100030006     2024-07-04  False
1786   CZ100030006     2024-07-04  False
1958   CZ100030006     2024-06-21  False
1964   CZ100030006     2024-06-21  False
4067   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4119   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4143   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4441   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4467   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4530   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4532   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4585   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4703   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
4767   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4850   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4888   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4974   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
4987   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
5108   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
5476   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
9768   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9815   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9822   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
9837   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9852   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9853   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9889   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
9945   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10009  CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10050  CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10052  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
10060  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
11532  CZ100030005     2024-06-20  False
11582  CZ100030005     2024-06-05  False
11640  CZ100030005     2024-06-20  False
11722  CZ100030005     2024-06-05  False
13267  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13339  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13354  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13655  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False

explaining the logic:
def f(x):
    unique = x.drop_duplicates()
    print(f'unique dates: {unique.tolist()}')
    top_2 = unique.nlargest(2)
    print(f'largest two: {top_2.tolist()}')
    print(f'equality to second largest ({top_2.iloc[-1]}):')
    print(x == top_2.iloc[-1])
    return x == top_2.iloc[-1]

(df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed']
   .transform(f)
)

Intermediates:
unique dates: [Timestamp('2024-07-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-08-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-06-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-06-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-09-25 00:00:00')]
largest two: [Timestamp('2024-09-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-08-28 00:00:00')]
equality to second largest (2024-08-28 00:00:00):
9768     False
9815     False
9822      True
9837     False
9852     False
9853     False
9889      True
9945     False
10009    False
10050    False
10052     True
10060     True
11532    False
11582    False
11640    False
11722    False
13267    False
13339    False
13354    False
13655    False
Name: CZ100030005, dtype: bool
unique dates: [Timestamp('2024-07-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-06-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-09-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-07-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-10-11 00:00:00')]
largest two: [Timestamp('2024-10-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-09-16 00:00:00')]
equality to second largest (2024-09-16 00:00:00):
1449    False
1786    False
1958    False
1964    False
4067     True
4119     True
4143    False
4441    False
4467    False
4530    False
4532     True
4585    False
4703    False
4767    False
4850    False
4888    False
4974    False
4987     True
5108    False
5476    False
Name: CZ100030006, dtype: bool


Thanks all, all answers working nicely, I have much to learn.

Can you please give me hint how lambda works? I do not mean lambda as such, but on which data nlargest works in that lambda function and what do I get with iloc?

@VladimirBuzalka I added a small correction, the lambda works by getting the unique dates, keeping the last of the largest 2 (i.e. the second largest) and comparing to the original series.

Super, that was confusing me :-) now dropduplicates explained everything

@VladimirBuzalka I'm adding a function to break down the steps

first, make conversion to datetime for proper comparisons
df['Date Dispensed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Dispensed'])

second, find the second maximum date for each subject
second_max_dates = df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).iloc[-1])

add a new column of second max to handle boolean
print(df)

sample result:
Subject Date Dispensed  Is Second Max
0   CZ100030006     2024-07-04          False

I think OP wants df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed'].transform(lambda x: x==x.nlargest(2).iloc[0])

Use GroupBy.rank with method='dense', ascending=False and compare by 2 for set True to second maximal value:
df['new'] = (df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed']
               .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
               .eq(2))


print (df)
           Subject Date Dispensed    new
1449   CZ100030006     2024-07-04  False
1786   CZ100030006     2024-07-04  False
1958   CZ100030006     2024-06-21  False
1964   CZ100030006     2024-06-21  False
4067   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4119   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4143   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4441   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4467   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4530   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4532   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
4585   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4703   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
4767   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4850   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4888   CZ100030006     2024-07-19  False
4974   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
4987   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   True
5108   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False
5476   CZ100030006     2024-10-11  False


9768   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9815   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9822   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
9837   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9852   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9853   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
9889   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
9945   CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10009  CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10050  CZ100030005     2024-07-04  False
10052  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
10060  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   True
11532  CZ100030005     2024-06-20  False
11582  CZ100030005     2024-06-05  False
11640  CZ100030005     2024-06-20  False
11722  CZ100030005     2024-06-05  False
13267  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13339  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13354  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
13655  CZ100030005     2024-09-25  False
    

How it working:
print (df.assign(rank= df.groupby('Subject')['Date Dispensed']
               .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)))

           Subject Date Dispensed  rank
1449   CZ100030006     2024-07-04   4.0
1786   CZ100030006     2024-07-04   4.0
1958   CZ100030006     2024-06-21   5.0
1964   CZ100030006     2024-06-21   5.0
4067   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   2.0
4119   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   2.0
4143   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4441   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4467   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4530   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4532   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   2.0
4585   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4703   CZ100030006     2024-10-11   1.0
4767   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4850   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4888   CZ100030006     2024-07-19   3.0
4974   CZ100030006     2024-10-11   1.0
4987   CZ100030006     2024-09-16   2.0
5108   CZ100030006     2024-10-11   1.0
5476   CZ100030006     2024-10-11   1.0


9768   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
9815   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
9822   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   2.0
9837   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
9852   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
9853   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
9889   CZ100030005     2024-08-28   2.0
9945   CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
10009  CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
10050  CZ100030005     2024-07-04   3.0
10052  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   2.0
10060  CZ100030005     2024-08-28   2.0
11532  CZ100030005     2024-06-20   4.0
11582  CZ100030005     2024-06-05   5.0
11640  CZ100030005     2024-06-20   4.0
11722  CZ100030005     2024-06-05   5.0
13267  CZ100030005     2024-09-25   1.0
13339  CZ100030005     2024-09-25   1.0
13354  CZ100030005     2024-09-25   1.0
13655  CZ100030005     2024-09-25   1.0
    

